# Get multiple input values from a Flask form before redirect

Tags: python, forms, flask, post

I have a form which displays a list of values as buttons.

```
products = [ant,bat,cat,dog,egg]
```

**Index.html**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('show_products') }}" method="post">
      <ul class="list-group">
       {% for p in products %}
        <input type="submit" name="{{p}}" value="{{p}}" >{{p}}</input> 
        {% endfor %}
      </ul> 
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Want to use this button to redirect</button>
    </form>
```

**In app.py**

```
@app.route('/show_products', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def show_products():
    result = []
    prod_data = {}
    if request.form:
            result = request.form
    prod_data['p_name'] = result
    return render('run_import.html', prod_data)
```

**show_products.html**

```
<h1>Hi</h1>
<p>p_name</p>
```

So everytime one of the products are clicked, ant, cat etc. The page **immediately redirect to show_products.html** and the name of the clicked product is shown.

I want the redirect to happen only when the button outside the for loop is clicked and every product that was clicked until then to be passed back as a list to show_products() and then to the html page.

Comment: can you share the route which is responsible for rendering the ```index.html``` templpate.

Comment: You could use `checkbox` to select multiple entries in a form and then one submit button. Would that help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a checkbox to capture multiple entries and send them back to flask on click of submit

*flask.py*

```py
@app.get('/')
def index():
    products = ['ant','bat','cat','dog','egg']
    return render_template('test.html', products=products)

@app.post('/show_products')
def show_products():
    products = request.form.getlist('products')
    return render_template('output.html', products=products)
```

You can use CSS to make the checkboxes as per your requirement

*test.html*

```
<form action="{{ url_for('show_products') }}" method="post">
    <ul class="list-group">
        {% for p in products %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="{{p}}">{{p}}</input>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Want to use this button to redirect</button>
</form>
```

*output.html*

```
<ul class="list-group">
    {% for p in products %}
        {{p}}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If you need to use buttons to capture the values, you will need an onClick listener on each button to store the values in a list and send the list over on click of submit